# React js Problem: Why my console.log print initial value where it changed page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Thank you for seeing this code. please take a look

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [starterModal, setStarterModal] = React.useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    let cronInterval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(starterModal);
    }, 4000);
    setStarterModal(false);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox </h1>
      <h1>starterModal {starterModal ? "True" : "False"} </h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My expected output of the state value is false. why the log print true inside setInterval

Comment: Specifically the part about closures in the top answer

Answer (score 0):

When the code `const [starterModal, setStarterModal] = React.useState(true);` runs, `starterModal` becomes a scalar value (not object). Scalar values are passed via value, meaning the value you get in you setInterval handler is stuck forever to what it was during initialisation.

calling `setStarterModal` would trigger render again, so your code would run again.

This article explains a solution to your case https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks (see Gotcha's section)